# Doubt about Poles of the Transfer Function

Tags: transfer-function

Why shouldn't the poles of a tf be in the RHP. I mean I know in a vague way, but what is the explanation/proof? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a system to be stable, the poles of the TF must be in the LHP. RHP can have poles if the system is not stable.

I don't remember the textbook proof of it. But the way I understood is explained below.

Consider a transfer function with two poles. One at RHP (\$p_1\$) and the other at LHP (\$-p_2\$). Then the transfer function will be of the form:
$$\frac{Y(s)}{X(s)} = \frac{A}{(s-p_1)(s+p_2)}$$

Assuming unit step input, \$x(t)= u(t),\$  output will be
$$Y(s) = \frac{A}{(s-p_1)(s+p_2)}\times \frac{1}{s}$$

Using partial fraction, Y(s) can be written as,
$$Y(s) = \frac{A_1}{s-p_1} + \frac{A_2}{s+p_2} + \frac{A_3}{s}$$

Where \$A_1, A_2, A_3\$ are constants. 
Taking Laplace inverse,

$$y(t) = (A_1e^{p_1} + A_2e^{-p_2} + A_3)u(t)$$

The first term \$A_1e^{p_1}\$ will go unbounded as \$t\rightarrow\infty\$ and so does the output. But the input is still bounded. So the system is not stable (see [BIBO stability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIBO_stability)).

The reason for instability is the presence of \$A_1e^{p_1}\$ term in the output which is contributed by the pole at RHP.

Conclusion: *The pole at RHP can contribute to an exponentially growing term in the output of the system which will lead to instability.*

Answer (score 1):

Supplementing nidhin`s answer, we learn from systems theory that the denominator D(s) of the transfer function (frequency domain) is identical to the characteristic polynominal P(s) belonging to the solution of the corresponding diff. equation (time domain). This characteristic polynominal results from an exponential "Ansatz" [exp(s*t)] for solving the diff. equation.

Hence, D(s)=P(s), and the solution of the characteristic equation P(s)=0 is identical to the poles of the transfer function H(s).

As mentioned already by nidhin, the **real part** of the exponents in the time domain solutions [exp(s*t)] must be NEGATIVE for stable systems (bounded output for bounded input). This is identical with the requirement to have only poles in the left half of the complex s-plane.